# how to count the number of Call voice minutes in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am building an application which generates the reports of the device usage.
I would like to Count the voice minutes user used iPhone for incoming and outgoing calls.
Any help/suggestion to do would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't acces these kinds of information. It is not exposed by the iOS SDK.

Comment: It used to be possible to gather this information through the system-logs. That loophole has been closed with iOS5.